Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis not honoring some Spring Cloud Stream Consumer properties
Through testing of our microservices that utilize Spring Cloud Stream, we have verified that the configuration below is not honored by the Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis when exceptions are encountered during stream processing (i.e., stream processing is not retried at all). When using the same configuration with the Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder configured, when exceptions are thrown, the consumer processing is retried.
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        bindingName:
          binder: kinesis
          consumer:
            back-off-initial-interval: 1000
            back-off-max-interval: 1000
            back-off-multiplier: 2.0
            max-attempts: 5

Is there a reason why the Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis does not honor these Spring Cloud Stream Consumer properties? Is the intent for the binder to implement them?

There is no delivery retry feature in the KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter. At the moment when we implemented it we realized that this functionality simply can be achieved with a RequestHandlerRetryAdvice on the consumer endpoint of the output channel for this KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter. The retry functionality in Kafka binder is done in the AbstractRetryingMessageListenerAdapter which is outside of Spring Integration scope and does exactly the same what we can with the mentioned RequestHandlerRetryAdvice or @Retryable on the service activator method.

The advantage of using Spring Cloud Stream (and Spring in general) is the entire premise of binding to the interface and not to the implementation. If Spring Cloud Stream specifies those properties (i.e., think of it as the interface), I would expect that every implementation of Spring Cloud Stream (i.e., the implementations, or the binders) would adhere to the interface specifications. To have the Kinesis binder not implement this feature of Spring Cloud Stream is confusing and doesn't adhere to the spirit of Spring in my opinion. Where are code examples of how to do what you described?

Well, this is not fully true because we would fall into a hell of YAML programming instead of nice old Java style. The binder was implemented after Spring Integration AWS and the way how we handled @StreamListener in the past was enough to deal with this situation for retries. In fact all those properties in Spring Cloud Stream Core are just recommendations, not requirements. I believe a @Retryable on your function method should be enough for now. I see your pain about consistency anyway, so feel free to raise a GH issue for Kinesis Binder!
